# JDeveloper designer not rendering

Tags: java, jdeveloper, designer

For some reason, in JDeveloper, trying to add a new .jsf page, it stalls at showing "Waiting for Designer to initialize Rendering page" and never completes the designer view.

Windows 7,
Oracle JDeveloper 12c,
Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.3.0,
java version "9.0.1",
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

Is there a version conflict or update needed?
thx

Answer (score 3):

It's hapening normally in each and everyone's machine.

> **Sollution** : Click on the source tab and wait in it for a while then click the design tab. Then you'll see the page.

It occurs to me too and I'm using that way.

Answer (score 0):

JDeveloper is not certified to work with JDK 9.
Try running it with JDK 8.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/122-cert-2708091.html